# How can I use ASP.NET MVC (or Core) to detect and redirect cookieless sessions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm creating a website where security conscious  (paranoid) people might block cookies, and even authentication cookies.

I'd like to detect this instance, and redirect to a FAQ/Help page that describes the [corresponding risks with cookieless sessions.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17719/396)

Comment: cookieless session means that your user shouldn't have any cookie ! If any page call creates a cookie in the response, you should  be able to check thrgouh an ajax call at page load if the cookie is set on the client. ... and do your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing terminology, so it's a little unclear what you're talking about. Sessions are either cookieless or not. If you're using cookieless sessions in ASP.NET, then every session is cookieless. As a result, it's kind of pointless to warn a user about the inherent security risks in something they are forced to use. If you're not using cookieless sessions, then every session requires a cookie, and again there's no point in warning a user about something that doesn't even apply to them.

The only thing that *would* make sense here, is to require a session cookie (no cookieless sessions) and then notify users without cookies enabled that they will not be able to utilize portions of your site that require cookies (authenticated areas and other places where you might utilize the session). To do that, you can either use JavaScript to detect whether cookies are enabled via `navigator.cookieEnabled` or you can do it server-side via:

1. Set a cookie or simply save something to the session (which will require a cookie to be set)
2. Redirect
3. Check for the previously set cookie or session data

If it exists after the redirect, then cookies are enabled. If not, then they are disabled.